# wxPython how do I retrieve information from a dialog box opened by a button

Tags: python, user-interface, events, wxpython

I'm trying to pull data from a text entry dialog box that's opened by a button click event using wxpython using this code.

```
import wx
class apple(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'PyLabs', size=(840,600))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, 'hi', 'hi', 'hi')


        status_bar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        options_menu = wx.Menu()
        options_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Settings", "OpenSettings...")
        options_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Advanced", "Check Advanced...")
        menu_bar.Append(options_menu, "Options")
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        New_Experiment_Button = wx.Button(panel, pos=(10,10), label='New Experiment', size=(120, 40))
        answer = self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openFrame, New_Experiment_Button)
        print(answer)


    def openFrame(self, event):
        box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, 'hi', 'hi', 'hi')
        if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            answer = str(box.getValue)
            event.Skip()
        return answer


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = apple(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm extremely new to wxpython coding and i don't understand how i'm to grab the data pulled by the button event when it's called from inside the Bind() function.

The output of print(answer) is "None"

If anybody could help me with this it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the print in the function, why would you need to return it to `def __init__` ?

```
 def openFrame(self, event):
    box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, 'hi', 'hi', 'hi')
    if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        answer = box.GetValue()
        event.Skip()
    print answer
```

Comment: I need to use the answer from the dialog box to be used as a variable in another function later on

Answer (score 0):

The "answer" is `box.GetValue()`, however you have a few more issues with your experiment, see below, check the differences

Edited with reference to your comments, store you result in a `self` variable and see the difference in the `Bind` statements on the buttons.

```
import wx
class apple(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'PyLabs', size=(840,600))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        status_bar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        options_menu = wx.Menu()
        options_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Settings", "OpenSettings...")
        options_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Advanced", "Check Advanced...")
        menu_bar.Append(options_menu, "Options")
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)
        New_Experiment_Button = wx.Button(panel, pos=(10,10), label='New Experiment', size=(130, 30))
        New_Experiment_Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openFrame)
        Result_Button = wx.Button(panel, pos=(10,60), label='Result of Experiment', size=(130, 30))
        Result_Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.resultValue)
        self.Text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "Nothing yet", pos=(10,100), size=(200,30))

    def openFrame(self, event):
        box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, 'What is your answer', 'Heading','Hi')
        if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.answer = box.GetValue()
        box.Destroy()

    def resultValue(self, event):
        try:
            self.Text.SetValue(self.answer)
        except:
            self.Text.SetValue("No answer yet supplied")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame = apple(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I need to get the value of the answer to use later as a variable in another function

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I actually need to use the answer from the entrydialog as a variable in another function later on

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!